# Which is superior, piezoelectric ultrasonic transducer or compression driver unit?

Tags: acoustics

I think the starting point is to raise the sound pressure level of the primary radiator in transmitting the audible sound as far as possible. In order to create the maximum sound pressure in generating the sound pressure of less than 20kHz, which one should I choose between the ultrasonic piezoelectric transducer and the compression driver unit? I know that compression driver units are used a lot in the audible band. However, I do not know if the ultrasonic piezoelectric transducer is superior in terms of volume or sensitivity. Please provide a document describing the advantages and advantages of the two converters.

Answer (score 1):

The piezo unit can reproduce higher frequencies than the normal compression driver and is far, far less expensive. It is also more efficient and extremely sensitive. But because the maximum vibration amplitude of the piezo is very very small, it requires many, many of them to produce the sound pressure level of even a small compression driver.

For these reasons you will find piezo transducers used in conjunction with compression drivers, to stretch the upper cutoff frequency of the system to beyond human audibility. This lets the speaker designer specify a less expensive compression driver and hence reduce the overall cost of the system.

This also means that if you want to produce very high SPL's at, say, 10,000 to 15,000Hz, you must use a large compression driver (1" throat diameter minimum plus 5 to 10 pounds of magnet structure) along with a large matching horn to properly match the driver impedance to that of air, and to point the radiation in the desired direction. Large, heavy, expensive. (You will also require a very powerful (several hundred watts RMS) amplifier to drive the unit).

You will find that all big (stadium-sized) sound systems use multiples of the largest compression drivers available and drive them with amps that produce *thousands* of watts of electrical power.